# Firewall - Allowing DNS for allowed domains only

Tags: firewall, dns, linux

Some firewalls blocks domains on DNS level. It stops getting IP addresses by ping or other DNS query for those blocked domains.

I tried creating a firewall using `iptables`, but it still sends an IP address back in a ping request response.

I was thinking of some rules that will filter DNS packets based on contents, and haven't found a way to do it. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to DNS server, you can setup Response Policy Zones (RPZ).

If you need to do it with iptables, check this out: [Stack Overflow: iptables rules to allow DNS queries for a specific domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096966/can-iptables-allow-dns-queries-only-for-a-certain-domain-name)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BIND, an alternate means would be to set up a non-recursive DNS (i.e., the global forwarders statement turned off) and then set up stub zones which point to the proper DNS servers for those domains.  In either case (configuring IPTables